# How to build shell plots based on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have the following dataframe of numbers of interactions between ligand-receptor pairs:

```
d = {'ligand': ['B cells','CAFs','Malignant cells','T cells','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TECs','unclassified'],
     'receptor': ['TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','B cells','CAFs','Malignant cells','T cells','TAMs','TECs','unclassified','TAMs','TAMs'],
    'interactions': [18, 29, 89, 22, 17, 12, 48, 34, 56, 27, 14, 53, 24]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I need to visualize the number of interactions between ligands and receptors. I am looking for something like this:
[image]

The description says these are shell plots. But I can't find that type of visualization anywhere. How to get this type of visualization using python modules?

Comment: Is that a standard plot? Is it something the authors made up?

Comment: This is not a standard type of graph. The authors must have wanted to make something "pretty". Unfortunately, this graph has many flaws, making it difficult to read and thus uninformative (to many colors as categories, quantitative information coded as text). Stay away from it and use a robust/explicit system (bargraph, network with lines of different thickness, heatmap...). Anything should be better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas library seemingly doesn't have any standard method to make such plots. So you could probably just extract the data from that data frame and try to draw those circles and connections between them in a typical matplotlib way. A basic example could be something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ligands = ['B cells','CAFs','Malignant cells','T cells','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TECs','unclassified']
receptors = ['TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','B cells','CAFs','Malignant cells','T cells','TAMs','TECs','unclassified','TAMs','TAMs']
interactions = [18, 29, 89, 22, 17, 12, 48, 34, 56, 27, 14, 53, 24]

# get the set of unique cell names
unique_cells = set(ligands)
num = len(unique_cells)

# make a figure with 2 rows of subplots
nrows=2
ncols=int(np.ceil(num/2))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar', 'frameon': False})
# turn the axes off
for m in range(nrows):
    for n in range(ncols):
        axes[m, n].set_axis_off()
# make a dictionary with polar coordinates of all cells, equally spaced along a big circle
angles = np.linspace(start=0, stop=360, num=num, endpoint=False)
radius = 5
radii = np.full(len(angles), radius)
locations = {d: (np.deg2rad(a), r) for d, a, r in zip(unique_cells, angles, radii)}
# define a color map and make colors for all cells
cmap = cm.tab20
colors = [cmap(c) for c in np.linspace(0, 1, num)]
for i, cell in enumerate(unique_cells):
    ax = axes[int(np.floor(i/ncols)), np.mod(i, ncols)]
    # show all cells on each subplot
    for a, r, name, color in zip(angles, radii, unique_cells, colors):
        t = np.deg2rad(a)
        ax.scatter(t, r, marker='o', s=150, color=color)
    # draw connections of the current cell to all the other ones
    for lig, rec, inter in zip(ligands, receptors, interactions):
        if cell == lig:
            theta, r = locations[lig]
            if lig != rec:
                # prepare a straightforward arrow and text alignment for a typical connection
                connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'
                val='center'
            else:
                # prepare a special kind of arrow and text alignment for connecting a cell to itself
                if theta >= 0 and theta < np.pi:
                    angleA = 45
                    angleB = 135
                    val='bottom'
                else:
                    angleA = -45
                    angleB = -135
                    val='top'
                connectionstyle='arc,angleA={},angleB={},armA=40,armB=40,rad=10'.format(angleA, angleB)
            
            # make an arrow with text
            ax.annotate(inter, locations[lig], locations[rec],
                        xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
                        size='small', color='black',
                        horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment=val,
                        arrowprops=dict(
                            arrowstyle='<-',
                            shrinkA=0,
                            shrinkB=0,
                            connectionstyle=connectionstyle
                        ),
                        )
            
    ax.set_rmax(radius + 2)

fig.legend(labels=unique_cells, loc='lower right')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

resulting in the following picture:

[image]

Please, refer to the matplotlib documentation to beautify the result, e.g. to improve [text annotations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/index.html) and [connections](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/connectionstyle_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connectionstyle-demo-py). Alternatively, you could try [plotly filled chord diagrams](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/).

One more way to visualize connections between a cell to many other cells could be [Sankey diagrams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/sankey_basics.html#sphx-glr-gallery-specialty-plots-sankey-basics-py), although your plot would look very different in this case (without any circles).

**UPDATE:**

Yet another way to make something like a shell plot could be drawing a circular graph with [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) library:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy

ligands = ['B cells','CAFs','Malignant cells','T cells','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TECs','unclassified']
receptors = ['TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','TAMs','B cells','CAFs','Malignant cells','T cells','TAMs','TECs','unclassified','TAMs','TAMs']
interactions = [18, 29, 89, 22, 17, 12, 48, 34, 56, 27, 14, 53, 24]

# get the set of unique cell names
unique_cells = set(ligands)
num = len(unique_cells)
codes = {u: c for u, c in zip(unique_cells, range(len(unique_cells)))}

# make a figure with 2 rows of subplots
nrows=2
ncols=int(np.ceil(num/2))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(15, 9), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.01, 'hspace': 0.01})

# turn the axes off
for a in axes.flatten():
    a.set_axis_off()

# define a color map and make colors for all cells
cmap = cm.tab20
colors = [cmap(c) for c in np.linspace(0, 1, num)]

# for each cell show its connections to all the other cells as a graph
for i, cell in enumerate(unique_cells):
    ax = axes[int(np.floor(i/ncols)), np.mod(i, ncols)]
    # make connections of the current cell to all the other ones
    edges = []
    for lig, rec, inter in zip(ligands, receptors, interactions):
        if cell == lig:
            edges.append((codes[lig], codes[rec], {'weight': inter}))
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(num))
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, with_labels=False, node_color=colors, edge_color=colors[codes[cell]])
    # place weight values as labels approx. in the middle of each typical edge connecting two different cells
    edge_labels = {(u, v): d['weight'] for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True) if u != v}
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, ax=ax, edge_labels=edge_labels, rotate=False, label_pos=0.45)
    # place a custom label slightly above the edges connecting a cell to itself (looking like a loop)
    loop_edge_labels = {(u, v): d['weight'] for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True) if u == v}
    tr = offset_copy(ax.transData, units='dots', y=37)
    for edge, weight in loop_edge_labels.items():
        ax.text(
                pos[edge[0]][0],
                pos[edge[0]][1],
                weight,
                horizontalalignment='left',
                verticalalignment='center',
                rotation=0,
                transform=tr
                )
    # draw a circular border around the current graph to separate it from the neighboring ones
    curve_x = -1.4 * np.cos(np.linspace(np.deg2rad(0), np.deg2rad(360), 100))
    curve_y = 1.4 * np.sin(np.linspace(np.deg2rad(0), np.deg2rad(360), 100))
    ax.plot(curve_x, curve_y, color='k', alpha=0.3, linestyle='--')
    ax.axis('equal')

# make the figure legend with colored circles designating the cells
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label=uc,
                          markerfacecolor=c, markersize=15) for uc, c in zip(unique_cells, colors)]
fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='upper center', ncols=4)
fig.savefig('cells.png')
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

In this way connection labels can be placed very easily in the middle of the respective edges with [draw_networkx_edge_labels](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html#draw-networkx-edge-labels). Loop-like edges (connecting a cell to itself) are generated automatically, although they are quite small and their labels seem to lump with the other contents of the plot. But you can place those labels separately as text.